# SSIS Wildcard Flat file connection

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

I want to load data from some csv files in a certain directory into a sql server table. The files are in the following format File_DDMMYYYHHMMSS.csv however I only want to select the files from the current day, the time doesn't matter. Is there a way to search files in this way? 
I have tried using a foreach loop and looking for only *.csv and setting a variable and then using:

```
LEFT(  @[User::FileName],5 ) +  
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DatePart("dd", GetDate()), 2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DatePart("mm", GetDate()), 2) + 
RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 4) DATEPART("yyyy", GetDate()), 4)
```

What i need is something like :

@filename + Todays date + "**__**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick google search yielded this [link](http://plexussql.blogspot.com/2010/06/chronological-order-list-files-by.html) that explains the exact method of doing this. Its  a dirty version of doing stuff, but gets the job done effectively.